# How to Check RadioButtonList when Option Selected is Changed?

Tags: asp.net, forms, .net-4.0, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have a .NET/ASP.NET based form that uses a RadioButtonList in which by default none of the options are selected:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Rb.ascx.cs" Inherits="Rb" %>
<table><tr><td align="left">
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioButtonList" runat="server">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</td><td valign="top">
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="radioButtonListValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="radioButtonList" ErrorMessage=": Please select an option." Text="*" ValidationGroup="validate">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

For one of the options in the list, **as soon as it's selected** I would like to generate a warning message box (rather than using some sort of description label or validation error message). So far as I can tell, there's no event handler for something like _SelectChanged. I was wondering how to implement such a feature to get something like this (below is semi-psuedocode because I'm not sure how to code what I want given the seemingly lack of an event handler for what I want):

```
public override void radioButtonList_SelectionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(radioButtonList.SelectedItem == "Option 2") //Where 'Option 2' is displayed on the actual form next to the radio button
    {
        Messagebox.Show("Warning: Selecting this option may release deadly neurotoxins");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way is checking the `Value` property of the item selected on the list control. 
You could use `SelectedValue` property, try something like this:

```
if(radioButtonList.SelectedValue == "Option 2")
{
   Messagebox.Show("Warning: Selecting this option may release deadly neurotoxins")
}
```

You also can check using `SelectedItem.Text` property.

```
if(radioButtonList.SelectedItem.Text == "Option 2")
{
   Messagebox.Show("Warning: Selecting this option may release deadly neurotoxins")
}
```

If you are on asp.net, you do not have Messagebox.Show, you should use a javascript alert.

Comment: Where would the code go? Page_Load? Wouldn't that only cause the alert after the user clicks the summit button (and in turn triggers a page load) for the form?

Comment: Where do you need to do this check?

Comment: I would like the check to happen as soon as the user selects an option from the radiobuttonlist (hence my original desire for some sort of event listener).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.I hope it helps.

```
if(radioButtonList.SelectedValue == "Option 2")
{
string script = "alert('Warning: Selecting this option may release deadly neurotoxins');";
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
}
```

Comment: Where would this go, in Page_Load? Wouldn't that then only generate an alert when a Page_Load is triggered by clicking the summit form button rather than 'instantly' when the user selects 'Option 2'?

Comment: Write this in radioButtonList_SelectionChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to solve this. it is much easier. here is a sample code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#<%=radioButtonList.ClientID%> input").change(function(){
          alert('test');
   });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never worked in the jquery space before. Your sample code seems to only operate on change. I want it to then check if the value of the radiobuttonlist selected is equal to something (eg option 2) and then bring up the alert. I've done a little research in jquery, but haven't figured out how to do something syntactically synonymous with C#/ASP.NET's `radioButtonList.SelectedValue == "Some Value"` Could you flesh out the jquery a bit more if it's not too much trouble?